# how I can update a string list with a feed of string every second?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

For example, i have one method `new_strings_feed()` that return a list of strings every second, like:

```py
1s:    ["this", "is"]
2s:    ["this", "was", "example"]
3s:    ["this", "is", "example"]
4s:    ["is", "example"] 
5s:    ["is", "an","example", "that"] 
6s:    ["an", "example", "that", "return", "strings"] #
```

i would like get this information very second,  but without loose past informations. example, if we are in sec 6 and I print my list:

```py
while(True):
    refresh_my_list(new_strings_feed(), mylist)
    print(mylist)
    time.sleep(1)
```

So mylist values during execution should be:

```py
1s:    ["this", "is"]
2s:    ["this", "was","example"]
3s:    ["this", "is", "example"]
4s:    ["this", "is", "example"]
5s:    ["this", "is", "an", "example", "that"] 
6s:    ["this", "is", "an", "example", "that", "return", "strings"] #
```

I've tried different types of comparisons, but I can't solve it.

Someone have a suggest how i can implement my "reflesh_my_list", keeping in mind that sublists are being received?

Example of `input` and `output`:

```
input:  ["this", "is"]
output: ["this", "is"]
input:  ["this", "was", "example"]
output: ["this", "was","example"]
input:  ["this", "is", "example"]
output: ["this", "is", "example"]
input:  ["is", "example"]
output: ["this", "is", "example"]
input:  ["is", "an", "example", "that"]
output: ["this", "is", "an", "example", "that"]
input:  ["an", "example", "that", "return", "strings"]
output: ["this", "is", "an" "example", "that", "return", "strings"]
```

Comment: It looks like this is some kind of string completion based on previous inputs. Could you give more details on what kind of completion you want to occur? Is it only matching the beginning of the input against previous inputs, or can the middle or end of the list be modified? If multiple previous inputs match, which one should be chosen? (The longest match, the most recent, other?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store previous inputs.

Rather than store strings in the trie, instead lists of strings are stored, in reverse order since we need suffix matching, not prefix matching.

The output matches the example output in the question, so I think this is what was requested - let me know if not.

Please see code comments for explanation.

```
inputs = [
    ["this", "is"],
    ["this", "was", "example"],
    ["this", "is", "example"],
    ["is", "example"],
    ["is", "an", "example", "that"],
    ["an", "example", "that", "return", "strings"]
]


class Trie:
    END = object()  # marker object that represents end of a list

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = {}

    def add(self, item):
        """
        Add an item to the trie
        :param item: the item to add
        :return: None
        """
        node = self.root

        for x in item:
            node = node.setdefault(x, {})  # either get the existing dictionary or create an empty one

        node[self.END] = None  # mark the end of the sequence

    def search(self, item):
        """
        Search of all items sequences that have been added to the trie that begin with `item`
        :param item: the item to search for
        :return: a generator that gives all matching sequences
        """
        node = self.root
        
        # find the node that contains all entries that begin with this prefix
        for x in item:
            if x in node:
                node = node[x]
            else:
                return
            
        # list all possibilities, excluding the common prefix
        yield from self.__iter__(node)

    def __iter__(self, node=None, prefix=()):
        node = self.root if node is None else node

        for k, v in node.items():
            if k is self.END:
                yield prefix
            else:
                yield from self.__iter__(node=v, prefix=prefix + (k,))


def main():
    trie = Trie()

    for inp in inputs:
        # simulate a received input
        print(f'{inp=}')
        out = inp

        # first try to match the entire input, then all but the last item, then all but the last 2
        # e.g. try ['an', 'example', 'that', 'return', 'strings'] - this isn't in the trie.
        # then, try ['an', 'example', 'that', 'return'] - this also isn't in the trie
        # then, try ['an', 'example', 'that'] - this matches ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'that']
        for i in reversed(range(len(inp))):
            # search in trie
            complete_options = list(trie.search(reversed(inp[:i + 1])))
            
            # if there is a match in the trie
            if complete_options:
                # find the best match 
                best_complete_option = max(complete_options, key=len)
                
                # concatenate the extra part onto the beginning
                out = list(reversed(best_complete_option)) + inp
                # stop looping
                break
                
        # add the result to the trie
        trie.add(reversed(out))

        print(f'{out=}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The time complexity of searching for matches for each input is `O(n^2+m)` where `n` is the list length and `m` is the extra part concatenated on. The `n^2` is because it iterates over `n` times in the `for i in reversed(range(len(inp)))` loop, and inside the loop it does a search, which is `O(n)`. There is also the conversion of the search results to a list and finding the longest, one - this can be eliminated by changing the search method to always list longer results first and just getting the first item from the generator:

```
class Trie:

    ...

    def __iter__(self, node=None, prefix=()):
        node = self.root if node is None else node

        for k, v in node.items():
            if k is not self.END:
                yield from self.__iter__(node=v, prefix=prefix + (k,))

        if self.END in node:
            yield prefix

...
def main():

    ...

    for inp in inputs:

        ...

        for i in reversed(range(len(inp))):
            # search in trie
            complete_options = trie.search(reversed(inp[:i + 1]))
            try:
                best_complete_option = next(complete_options)
                out = list(reversed(best_complete_option)) + inp
                # stop looping
                break
            except StopIteration:
                # there were no complete_options
                pass
```

Comment: :o WOW this works!! I'm studying your code, but what I can say is! THANKS. No reputation for upvote yet, but soon I'll be up your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

append method is what you are looking for, dont know what this "refresh_my_list" function does but
if you have a list like this:

```
sample_array = ["this", "is", "an" "example", "that", "return", "strings"]
import time
output_array=[]

for item in sample_array:
    output_array.append(item)
    print(output_array)
    time.sleep(1)
```

this should do what you want :)

Comment: oh thanks for your answer. but I don't have the final array like "sample_array". it's like a flow. I get parts of the sample array that come with information already come has or without that, so I need to know which part to consider and which part to disregard. Make sense?

Comment: Not sure if i understood you correcly but are you saying that your inputs are keep coming to you? like lets say we have 3 words now 4th word can get to our function maybe an hour later or a minute later and then our function should still remember the previous 3 words and put last one so prints out 4 words right?

Comment: Almost like that... I tried to formulate an example but it's like simultaneous subtitling. I need to do some word pair comparisons or even N words, around this, to ensure I'm concatenating the subvector correctly.

Comment: Notice the moments when I keep something I've already received and the moments I need to replace some words. for the human it's easy but I'd like to concatenate without getting all the words from all the feeds

something like `["this", "is", "an" "example", "that", "return", "strings"]`
and not all lists like  `["this", "is", "this", "was", "example", "this", "is", "example", "is", "example", "is", "an", "example", "that","this", "is", "an", "example", "that","an", "example", "that", "return", "strings"]`

Comment: got it ok i will try to solve it using a dictionary (hashtable) i tried some stuff getting closer :) will let you know